# A grep function I've been using does not seem to be working correctly and I can't figure out why?

Tags: r

I have two rather large data frames that I would like to match with each other. My own data frame (Companies) consists of 1812 companies which I've exported to google doc so you can easily view them all:

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HV8-TfvuXLVFaX6bHGYea8D4afYYO6aQbyQysvq2974)

The other data frame (Master_list) that I have is very large with a couple of million observations, so I can't unfortunately show that, but it basically consists of many other companies. What I want is to retrieve the names of the companies in "Master_list" based on the company names from my data frame "Companies".

The spellings of these company names have slight variations between the two data frames. So an exact match is not possible for most of the strings.

Here is the structure of my data frame:

```
> str(Companies)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1812 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Companies_Generated: chr  "TOPSOE FUEL CELL" "HALDOR TOPSØE" "DKFZ DEUTSCHES KREBSFORSCHUNGSZENTRUM" "NIL TECHNOLOGY" ...
```

The function that I use to achieve the matching is this:

```
Matches.grep <- unique (grep(paste(Companies$Companies_Generated,collapse="|"), 
                         Master_list$Names, value=TRUE))
```

This takes appo. 2.5-3 hours to execute, and it seems to retrieve thousands of strange observations.

As an example, R retrieves the name "PIENA INC" in Matches.grep, and neither of those words appear in my "Companies" data frame so I do not know what makes R retrieve this name as a match?

I've been testing this out many times with a much smaller sample size and every time it seems to work without a problem, but when I use my large actual sample size, I get these unrelated matches seemingly from nowhere.

I'm sorry that I can't provide any examples, but it seems like whenever I use a much smaller sample, it works correctly.

Comment: This is almost definitely not a good approach. The clue is in the 3 hour execution time. You are trying to match to a very, very long regex. Do you know that your company names don't contain arbitrary special characters (e.g. `.` or `(`) which will screw the regex up?

Comment: try: `Master_list[Master_list$Names %in% Companies$Companies_Generated, ]`

Comment: If you know the company names are *the same* in the two data frames, then what is wrong with `dplyr::inner_join`, which should take at most minutes?

Comment: I would have imagined you should use `unique` around `Companies$Companies_Generated` rather than waiting until after you have pasted with 'collapse'-ation. Perhaps trying to `merge` would be more sensible?

Comment: @dash2 When I tried to remove the "pattern" function, I get an error saying "argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" so I haven't been able to find any workarounds yet unfortunately. My company names do not contain any arbitrary characters however they aren't quite the same as the names in the "Master_list" df. For example, I might have written "MICROSOFT" in my "Companies" df and the "Master_list" df might have "MICROSOFT LTD", but I still want R to retrieve "MICROSOFT LTD" from the "Master_list" df since it's obviously the same company.

Comment: @missuse Thank you, I will have a look at this and see if it helps.

Comment: @dash2 How would you go about using the inner join function? Unfortunately, the names aren't quite the same but have some variations. My theory was that by reducing my company names to simply "MICROSOFT", I should be able to retrieve variations like "MICROSOFT INC", "MICROSOFT LTD", etc.

Comment: I didn't suggest removing the pattern argument. Anyway, creating a megalong regex is always going to be very slow. You might want to use `amatch` for approximate matching; alternatively, you might be able to edit one column to make sure it is the same as the other.

Comment: @42- I did try to use "unique" before executing the command to ensure there aren't any dublicates. The unique at the end was in case an observations from the "Master_list" got retrieved more than once. I'm not sure if I can use the merge function however since the company names have slight variations.

Comment: I'd suggest showing some data in the question, so people can figure out the easiest way to get your columns to join nicely.

Comment: If you really have to use `grep`, you might find `lapply(column1, grep, x = column2, value = TRUE)` would be quicker.

Comment: Your response is the first time I read that there was an issue with inexact matches. but I see it was implied by a later comment. That was _essential_ information and should have been put in the body of the question. Attempting inexact matching is more of a natural language processing problem. It will be difficult with regex.

Comment: @dash2 Is amatch the same as the %in% function in R? It also doesn't necessarily have to be grep. Grep was simply what my limited knowledge of R could come up with. I'm open for any other commands and userpackages.

Comment: @42- I'm sorry for not making that clear earlier. I have edited the main body to include this information. Do you have any suggestions for what I could use in R for inexact matching?

Comment: There is an agrep function, but I also think your current quest should have a [MCVE] and should be shortened since there is now a lot of excess commentary that is not really needed and the number of comments reflects the lack of clarity and accuracy in the initial question.

Comment: @42- Thanks for the feedback, I will try rewriting a new question with a proper example and more clear information.